# What is the best way to measure the effectiveness of node cluster?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, load-balancing, stress-testing

I am using pm2 in my app (ubuntu 14.04, 2cpu 4gb ram).

I want to load-test or stress test the load-balance between clusters (I hope i'm saying it right) for it's effectiveness, What is the best way to do so?

I am using latest node.js (0.12.7) and latest pm version, i have 2 clusters going for me, 1 for each cpu.

Now i need to check response time when my server is at it's limits, even to see when it crashes and why (It's a staging server so i don't mind)

I know 'siege', used it a bit, not the one i want, i want something that can push the server to it's limits...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try http://loadme.socialtalents.com

In case free tier will be not enough you can request quota increase.